# Is @CEntryPoint supported in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I'm working on a Quarkus project, and am enjoying how much quicker it is to develop, compared to normal Java.

I'm interested to know whether all GraalVm and Substrate features are available, and in particular if the `@CEntryPoint` annotation is available and usable?

I recently read a blog article about how to make Java code usable in c++ using Graal and this annotation.

If this is possible it would open up a lot of possibilities, such as creating python modules, that call a Quarkus or Graal shared object.

Answer (score 1):

This should just work, this is a Graal VM feature so should not require any specific support in Quarkus.